# Using "inline-block" for multiple div tags

Tags: css, display

I have 2 div elements with the same class right next to each other.
They have `display: inline-block` as their style. How do I put them at the same height as shown on the picture: [image: a part of the page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the divs a `vertical-align:top` rule. The default vertical alignment for inline elements is `baseline`.

Comment: One more quick question, let's say I added another container right after the second one (which is shorter in height than the first one), can I make the third one stay under the second one (to the right of the first one) without the use of tables?

Comment: Probably, but you'll need to post a [mcve] so that we can see some actual code and reproduce what you're describing.

Answer (score 2):

Use vertical align to align divs to the top

```css
.mDiv{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  float:left;
}

.mDiv2{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width:300px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:blue;
   float:left;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class='mDiv'>1</div>
<div class='mDiv2'>2</div>
</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

I would float: left them instead of display: inline-block